# Turtle movement along a link list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of links : [(link 2226 2417) (link 1650 2226) (link 1650 1916) (link 1682 1916) (link 1107 1682)]. How can I move a turtle from (link 2226 2417) to (link 1107 1682) ?

By using nw:turtles-on-path-to from NW extension and by using the code of Marine with least cost paths (I modified it to work) :

```
to least-cost-path [ID-individual ID-polygon] 
let cost-of-path -1
let path []
let individuals-on-path []

ask wolves with [ who = ID-individual] [ 
 foreach sort nodes-on patches with [plabel = ID-polygon] [ 
  let node-on-polygon ? 
  nw:set-snapshot nodes links

  ask nodes-here [ 
   let cost nw:weighted-distance-to node-on-polygon "cost-of-link" 
   if cost-of-path = -1 or cost < cost-of-path [ 
    set cost-of-path cost 
    set path nw:weighted-path-to node-on-polygon "cost-of-link" 
    set individuals-on-path nw:turtles-on-path-to node-on-polygon ] ] ] ]

print cost-of-path
print path
print individuals-on-path

foreach path [
 ask ? [ set color red
 set thickness 0.2 ] ]

ask wolves [
foreach individuals-on-path [
face ? 
move-to ? ] ]

end
```

There is a problem with the results of "path" and "individuals-on-path": Logically, I should have (node 1669) after (node 982). Consequently, the wolve moves in a straight line and not along the path.

path = [(link 982 1669) (link 1353 1669) (link 1115 1353) (link 1115 1276) (link 1276 1983) (link 479 1983) (link 479 2319) (link 345 2319) (link 345 1023) (link 145 1023) (link 145 1808) (link 738 1808) (link 738 1793) (link 1097 1793) (link 1097 2523) (link 380 2523) (link 380 1582) (link 469 1582) (link 469 1278) (link 1277 1278) (link 391 1277) (link 391 2175) (link 208 2175)]

individuals-on-path = [(node 982) (node 1616) (node 1623) (node 2438) (node 749) (node 1435) (node 1584) (node 1396) (node 928) (node 939) (node 209) (node 1160) (node 1191) (node 1537) (node 806) (node 1222) (node 1762) (node 1245) (node 1274) (node 208)]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trickier than it seems, right?

I don't know what your overall context is, but the [`nw:turtles-on-path-to`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#path-to-turtles-on-path-to-weighted-path-to-turtles-on-weighted-path-to) primitive from the [NW extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension) could perhaps be useful to you.

If you can't use `nw:turtles-on-path-to`, you'll have to do it in NetLogo. What I have written below requires you to supply the start node. (Eliminating that requirement is non-trivial.) Here it is:

```
to-report node-list [ link-list start-node ]

  ; report an empty list when we're done:
  if empty? link-list [ report [] ]

  ; also report an empty list if given start
  ; node is not part of the first link:
  let ends [ both-ends ] of first link-list
  if not member? start-node ends [ report [] ]

  ; the "other node" is the end that is not the start-node
  let other-node [ one-of other ends ] of start-node

  ; if we had only one link, report a list with the two nodes
  if length link-list = 1 [ report list start-node other-node ]

  ; if we still have other links, put our start node at the front 
  ; of the result list and build the rest recursively, using
  ; other-node as a starting point for the rest of link-list  
  report fput start-node node-list but-first link-list other-node

end
```

Now let's see it in action:

```
to setup
  ca
  ; create a simple "path" network for demoing:
  crt 1
  crt 9 [ create-link-with turtle (who - 1) ]
  ask turtles [ set shape "dot" ]
  layout-circle turtles 8
end

to walk
  let list-of-links (sort links) ; supply your own list here...
  let list-of-nodes node-list list-of-links turtle 0
  crt 1 [ ; create our "walker"
    foreach list-of-nodes [
      face ?
      display wait 0.2 ; just to show what's going on
      move-to ?
      display wait 0.2 ; just to show what's going on
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. I modified the code using nw:turtles-on-path-to.

Comment: Hum... you modified your question completely after I answered, and despite the fact that you now mention `nw:turtles-on-path-to` in your question, you don't use it in the code you posted... I'm not sure I follow you... have you now resolved your problem?

Comment: Nell, if you changed your code to use `nw:path-to` but you're getting unexpected results, I'd suggest opening a new question on that rather than trying to pile it into this one.

Comment: Sorry. I modified the code. These results appear when I use nw:turtles-on-path-to. I have not revolved my problem.

Comment: Did you mean to use `nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to` instead of `nw:turtles-on-path-to`? If you don't include `-weighted-`, it won't take the link weights into account. That could be the reason for the discrepancy you're seeing between `path` and `individuals-on-path`.